# How do you prove a piece of the Short Five Lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be a homomorphism of short exact sequences, in that order.  Then if $\alpha, \gamma$ are injective, then so is $\beta$.

Let the sequeces be:
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & \to & A & \xrightarrow{\psi} & B & \xrightarrow{\phi} & C & \to & 0 \\
\ & \   & \downarrow^{\alpha} & \ & \downarrow^{\beta} \ & \ & \downarrow^{\gamma} \\
0 & \to & A' & \xrightarrow{\psi'} & B' & \xrightarrow{\phi'} & C' & \to & 0
\end{matrix}
$$

Then since $\psi, \psi', \alpha$ are injective and $\beta \psi = \psi' \alpha$, we have that $\beta$ is injective on $\psi(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reluctant to use the book, but ended up resorting to it.  Here's my understanding of the proof.

Suppose $\beta(b) = 0$.  Then $\gamma \phi(b) = \phi'\beta(b) = \phi'(0) = 0$, so $\phi(b) = 0$ by injectivity of $\gamma$.  Then $\ker \beta \subset \ker \phi = \psi(A)$.  So our $b = \psi(a)$ for some $a \in A$.  By commuting diagrams again $\beta \psi (a) = 0 =\psi' \alpha (a) $, and by injectivity $a = 0$, so $b = \psi(0) = 0$.  We're done.

There was just more usefulness for the diagram that I didn't see!

Comment: why we suppose $\beta (b) = 0$?

Comment: "$\phi (b)=0$ by injectivity of $\gamma$" I do not understand this statement, could you say it in details please?

Comment: @Emptymind We want to show that $\beta$ is injective. To do this, we attempt to show that ker $\beta$ is trivial. Hence we suppose $\beta(b) = 0$ and show that $b$ is the identity in $B$.